# caught ReferenceError: openFile is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onchange

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and trying to read a CSV file using a solution I found but I keep getting an error. The code:

```
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <title> Login </title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <label> Username: </label>
            <input> 
            <label> Password: </label>
            <input>
            <button id = "CredentialsButton"> Register or Login </button>
            <input type='file' accept='.csv' onchange='openFile(event)'>
        </main>
        <script type="module">
            import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.19.1/firebase-app.js";
            const firebaseConfig = {
                apiKey: "AIzaSyCslXhVh4mFT8NUyRLYOlO-ECfXr0f2cG8",
                authDomain: "unlimited-weddle.firebaseapp.com",
                projectId: "unlimited-weddle",
                storageBucket: "unlimited-weddle.appspot.com",
                messagingSenderId: "12999230493",
                appId: "1:12999230493:web:02a799c6276d0e7bbc32f4",
                measurementId: "G-PRJZN3T930"
            };
            const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
            import { getFirestore, doc, getDoc, setDoc, collection, addDoc, updateDoc, deleteDoc, deleteField } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.19.1/firebase-firestore.js";
            const db = getFirestore();
            var CredentialsButton = document.getElementById("CredentialsButton");
            var openFile = function(event) {
            var input = event.target;
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function() {
                    var text = reader.result;
                    var node = document.getElementById('output');
                    node.innerText = text;
                    console.log(reader.result);
                };
                reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the error I get is:
`caught ReferenceError: openFile is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onchange ((index):15:73)`
I've tried looking for solutions but I am relatively new to this and it confuses me, thank you.